# Secret key authentication in salesforce.com

Tags: authentication, salesforce

Is there a good way to do secret key authentication for http queries from a salesforce app to my own web server? In other words, I'd like to give each company that installs our application their own secret key. Then each http call the app makes to our server (whether json or just a link to a hosted iframe) would look something like this:

```
groupid = groupid 
param1 = value1
param2 = value2
signParam = signValue
```

Where `signValue = md5("groupid=groupid,param1=value1,param2=value2,secretKey"`

Then when I receive the query, I calculate the signature as well to make sure it matches before I perform any actions on our web server. The problem is, I don't see how I can assign and store the secret key for each company that installs our app (that is, have them store the secret key in their installation).

Is there a good way to do this that I'm missing? And if this isn't possible in salesforce, how else do you authenticate web queries before you perform actions in your own server?

Comment: Another option would be for salesforce to just assign us a secret key for our developer account... and we could refer to that key in our controller class as we generate requests. That'd work too... but only if users did not have access to the secret key. Anyone have thoughts on this?

Answer (score 3):

Rather than trying to track it on the salesforce side, have the salesforce side send the users sessionId to your webservice, you can then use the API to validate that sessionId get details about the user, and check locally that the particular user/organization is licensed.  There's some articles on the developerforce wiki about using this approach.